# Checking grammar using a custom module for all possible combinations of words in string

Tags: python, parsing, nltk, permutation

I am creating a software for a school, where students would actually type in sentence and then their grammar would be checked however they would be given random combination of words like

```
    The brown quick fox fence over jumped the
```

from this they would have to figure out the sentence and rewrite the sentence with correct grammar. When their answer is wrong, I want the program to rearrange the sentence for all possible combinations and then check the grammar for every single possible combination.

To get the random arrangement of sentences I use,

```
    text = raw_input("You:")
    #shuffling for all possibilities
    def randm(text):
          text = text.split(" ")
          for i in itertools.permutations(text): 
                    rnd_text = " ".join(i)
```

And then I have my own module to check grammar with the method,

```
    engrammar.grammar_cache(rnd_text)
```

When rnd_text is passed as the argument for the above method, if it is grammatically correct, the rearranged text will be displayed with correct grammar. So how do I pass **a single output from the "for loop" one at a time to the method that I have to check grammar FOR ALL POSSIBLE OUTPUTS?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to turn your function into a generator.

```
def randm(text):
      text = text.split(" ")
      for i in itertools.permutations(text): 
                yield " ".join(i)
```

Then all you have to do is

```
for word in randm(text):
    engrammar.grammar_cache(word)
```

You can read more about generators [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

If you don't want to use generators, you can always return a list from your function and then iterate through that list.

```
def randm(text):
      words = []
      text = text.split(" ")
      for i in itertools.permutations(text): 
                words.append(" ".join(i))
      return words

words = randm(text)
for word in words:
    engrammar.grammar_cache(word)
```

Comment: The generator approach will be more memory-friendly, and will also short-circuit - that is, you won't have to build the complete list of all permutations, only as many until the permutation with correct grammar is generated. This will probably cut your response time too - in half, on average I would guess.